# How to install pyqt5 and pyqt5-tools without using pip?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt4

Anyone help me,
how to install pyqt5 and pyqt5-tools without using pip?

Thank you

Comment: Where ? Linux, Mac, Windows ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source packpage of pyqt5 here:
https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5

Descompress him with the above command (Or with a program of your choice):

```
tar -xvf yourfile.tar
```

then cd in the output folder and run the above command to install pyqt5:

```
python3 configure.py
```

With this process you may install the both packpages.
Dont forget to change 'yourfile.tar' with the name of the downloaded file for your operational system.